# yadcf filter option with & char

Tags: jquery, datatable, yadcf

I have installed version 0.9.4 of this plugin
http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com
on my page. It works but when in column filter is a name with & char it not working.

Test on page:
https://woolflan.pl/modus/public.home
login: test
pass: test

Sometimes (maybe it because of a problem with & char) filters are off (no one is set) but grid didn't show anything. When I run a web browser in incognito mode there is no problem.

Comment: you init your table with `"bStateSave": true,` which cause the table to remember the filtering (thats why incognito "works" for you as to the filtering, try filtering with datatables "global filter input" (upper right corner) and anyway provide a minimal test page on jsfillde because I can't debug that table on your server like this

Comment: I will try to set bStateSave to false (it is not necessary) and hope it will solve problem nr 2 but set an example on https://jsfiddle.net/ is quite difficult and You can check how it works - or not - (& in any field) on even Your own page. You only need data in any cell with a & char.